# Scrapy Xpath query to select input tag elements

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy crawl spider and trying to parse output pages to select all input tag parameter as the following :

- input type: must be (text or password or file)
- input id: if it's not found , select [input name] instead.

I wrote a sample code for test in Scrapy shell, but it doesn't give me the exact result.

Tested site: http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com/Signup.aspx

```
>>> hxs.select('//input[@id] | //input[@type="text"] | /text()').extract()

[u'<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTY0MzI4NjU4Mw9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgQCAQ8WBB4EaHJlZgUKbG9naW4uYXNweB4JaW5uZXJodG1sBQVsb2dpbmQCAw8WBB8AZB4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZHEZ3VN6SP/C2xESDN/Y3p8zhfSB">',

 u'<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="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">',
 
  u'<input name="tbUsername" type="text" id="tbUsername" class="Login">',
  
  u'<input name="tbPassword" type="password" id="tbPassword" class="Login">',
  
  u'<input type="submit" name="btnSignup" value="Sign me up" id="btnSignup">']
```

Answer (score 2):

All `input` elements of type `text`, `password` or `file`:

```
//input[@type='text' or @type='password' or @type='file']
```

I am not sure of what condition you want on the id or name - this will get all `input` elements of those three types that have either an id or name:

```
//input[(@type='text' or @type='password' or @type='file') and (@id or @name)]
```

If you want to test for the id or name (if the id does not exists) equal to something (`XXXX`):

```
//input[(@type='text' or @type='password' or @type='file') and (@id='XXXX' or (not(@id) and @name='XXXX'))]
```

If you want to extract the id:

```
//input[@type='text' or @type='password' or @type='file']/@id
```

I don't think extracing either the id or the name if the id is not specified is possible with standard XPaths.

Comment: thanks alot for help , but i got this error(also the same error above  [error picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhj5exle5pof7wz/s_invalid.png)

Comment: i also thought it may be Quoting problem , so i used triple quotes ,but i got an empty list as a resullt [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3d77ad310b4ust2/tripleQuotes.png)

Comment: Try using single quotes inside the XPath (in XPath single and double quotes are equivalente - so if you have to use double quotes to delimit the whole XPath you can usually use single ones inside the XPath)

Comment: still got empty list ,, please help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, no idea - that XPath works OK on that page converted to XML, I don't have scrapy to test it with

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Scrapy, but from a purely XPath point of view, the following should satisfy the requirements you describe:

```
//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'text' or @type = 'password' or @type = 'file')]
```

Also, I notice you're trying to retrieve the text content of the selected nodes. This will presumably return nothing because inputs are self-closing tags and do not hold inner content.

Comment: `| /text()` is any text right under the root (that does not make much sense) - not the text of the selected nodes

Comment: thanks alot for help , but i got this error [error picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhj5exle5pof7wz/s_invalid.png)

Comment: That looks to be because you're using single quotes inside single quotes. Make yours double, i.e. the ones that wrap the entire XPath expression.

Comment: @Utkanos i also thought it may be Quoting problem , so i used triple quotes ,but i got an empty list as a resullt [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3d77ad310b4ust2/tripleQuotes.png)

Comment: i also tried 
`>>> hxs.select(""" //input[@type="text" or @type="password" or @type="file"]/text()""").extract()

` but it gave me also an empty list

Comment: That's still quotes within quotes. I meant wrap the XPath expression in double quotes (just one set, not three) and use only single quotes in the XPath expression itself.

Comment: @Utkanos `>>> hxs.select(" //input[@type='text' or @type='password' or @type='file']/text()").extract() >>> o/p [] `still empty llist

Comment: @Utkanos what about using lxml for parsing with scrapy , would it be better ?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Might be worth putting a bounty on the question to see if someone else can help.